# Call to empty constructor and base with parameters

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

My code goes like

```
public class Student : Person
{
    public Student() : base()
    {
         m_name = "No Name";
    }

    public Student(string path) : base(path)
    {

    }
}

public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
    }
    public Person(string path)
    {
         //..do something with path
    }
}
```

Now, I want to call-

```
Person myStudent = new Student("some path");
```

and I want it call the empty Ctor and also call base(path) ctor

so i'll get a Student instance with property m_name = "No Name"

Thanks

Comment: You can't because your classes are made to avoid that. Just change their design (moreover...when you **use** a class you shouldn't be aware of such implementation details, something is inherently wrong with this!)

Comment: You can't. You can't call two constructors, but you can chain it. Whay stops you from adding `m_name = "No Name";` in `Student(string path)` ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel `Student(string path)` was just a **short** example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use optional parameters to unify your constructor logic.

```
public class Student : Person
{
    public Student(string path = null) : base(path)
    {

    }
}

public class Person
{
    public Person(string path = null)
    {
        path = path ?? "sensible default";
    }
}
```

Comment: ChaosPandion I just looking for a nice solution because to two Ctors have different implementation in the base class (i'm reading some file). And your solution is OK, but it just adding me another check i wonted to avoid

Comment: @Eli - You can make this work quite cleanly if you extract 2 private methods and add one if statement that will call the proper method depending on whether `path` is null or not.